# What is the title limit length from the shares on google+?

Tags: google-plus, facebook-opengraph, schema.org

I need to know the length limit parameters for the meta tags for google +, and search the documentation and could not find information.

[Documentation.](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/)

Comment: i add a large title and the maximum length is 315
https://plus.google.com/107389385306786261571/posts/SZ7RqHbuu1r

Comment: The max length is not explicitly [documented](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/) so you shouldn't rely on that number for anything of importance.